# Is it possible to get the xml_id from JS code in Odoo?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to get a specific menuitem and store it in a variable in JavaScript:

```
var Menus = new openerp.web.Model('ir.ui.menu');
```

Now, we can apply a filter to `Menus` to get the menuitem, for example, look for its name, but the thing is that there are a lot of menuitems with the same name. So I think that the only attribute which identifies my menuitem and differences it from the other is the XML ID.

But I do not know how to get it from JavaScript code. Is there any built function to obtain it? How can I manage my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found a workaround. May be there is a better solution, in that case, please, post it.

In the database, there is a table named `ir_model_data`. This table stores the XML IDs, under the column `name`. The columns `model` and `res_id` indicate you the model where that XML ID record was stored and its ID. There is also a column named `module`, which can be used to put that before the XML ID extracted (column `name`), to get the *module_name.xml_id* notation.

For example:

I have a record from `ir.ui.menu` model with ID 303, and I want to get its XML ID from Javascript:

```
var Menus = new openerp.web.Model('ir.model.data');
Menus.query(['name']).filter(['&', ['model', '=', 'ir.ui.menu'], ['res_id', '=', 303]]).all().then(function(ir_model_datas) {
   for (i in ir_model_datas) {
      console.log(ir_model_datas[i].name);
   }
});
```